# Replicating a Character String Up to a certain point in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I currently have the following dataframe below:

```
Country Information Export Import
Andorra Small       10     20  
        Medium      50     30  
        Large       40     50  
Total   NA          100    100     
Antigua Small       60     70
        Medium      20     10
        Large       5      10
        X-Large     15     10  
Total   NA          100    100
```

I would like to repeat the Country name up until it reaches the character string "Total", so i would have Andorra repeated for rows in the column named $Country up until it reaches the row "Total"

As you can see the rows differ for nearly every country ( i have 252 of them) so i need to find a way to ensure that the country name is repeated for that specific country up until it reaches "total"

(e.g. Antigua has 4 rows not 3 like Andorra - so would require Antigua to be repeated 4 times in the $Country column)

Is there a quick and efficient way to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the fill function from the tidyr package

**Input Data**

```
df <- data.table::fread("Country    Information Export  Import
Andorra Small   10  20
NA  Medium  50  30
NA  Large   40  50
Total   NA  100 100
Antigua Small   60  70
NA  Medium  20  10
NA  Large   5   10
NA  X-Large 15  10
Total   NA  100 100")
```

**Code to Fill in missing information using fill from tidyr**

```
library(tidyr)
fill(df, Country, .direction = "down")
```

**Output**

```
   Country Information Export Import
1: Andorra       Small     10     20
2: Andorra      Medium     50     30
3: Andorra       Large     40     50
4:   Total        <NA>    100    100
5: Antigua       Small     60     70
6: Antigua      Medium     20     10
7: Antigua       Large      5     10
8: Antigua     X-Large     15     10
9:   Total        <NA>    100    100
```

If there are zero length string values, instead of NA, you can use the `na_if` function from the `dplyr` package to change them to `NA`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Country = na_if(Country,"")) %>% 
  fill(Country, .direction = "down")
```

Comment: I have encountered an error > I tried the fill function on my dataframe but it is not working at all, i ran fill(df, Country (the country column), .direction = "down") but nothing happend

Comment: I assume because the values are blank and not NA i am encountering this problem, I will change the values to NA for the values in which it is blank and try again?

Comment: That is correct, fill will not replace a zero length string, just NA values.  An easy way to change values to NA is using the `na_if` function from the dplyr package

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have `NA` values and not blank values in those cases that `country` values are missing.

You need to use function `na.locf` from package `zoo` and apply it on your `country` column, like this:

```
library(zoo)

# example of column values
country = c("Andorra",NA,NA,"Total","Antigua",NA,NA,NA,"Total")

# apply fucntion and update your variable
country = na.locf(country)

# see updated values
country
# [1] "Andorra" "Andorra" "Andorra" "Total"   "Antigua" "Antigua" "Antigua" "Antigua" "Total"
```

What it does is replacing `NA` values with the previous non-`NA` value.

Comment: `fromLast = FALSE` is the default so you don't have to specify it.